# How to have ingrained navigation bar look?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to have a navigation bar that doesn't have any extra space on the sides and on the top and bottom. However nothing seems to be. Is there a way I can fix this. An example of how I would like my navigation bar to look is dootrix.com 
Here is an image to illustrate what the problem is: [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pkjf0.png)

```css
     ul {
           list-style-type: none;
           margin: 0;
           padding: 0;
           overflow: hidden;
           background-color: mediumblue;
           text-align: center;
        object-position: fixed;
           width: 100%;
           top: 0;
         }
         li {
           display: inline-block;
         }
         li a {
           display: block;
           color: white;
           padding: 14px 50px;
           text-decoration: none;
         }
         li a:hover:not(.active) {
           background-color: darkblue;
      font-style: italic;
         }
```

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
     <meta charset="utf-8">
     <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
     <!-- Navigation Bar -->
     <ul>
      <li>
       <a href="test_webpage.html#about">ABOUT</a>
      </li>
      <li>
       <a href="test_webpage.html#products">PRODUCTS</a>
      </li>
      <li>
       <a href="test_webpage.html#coupons">COUPONS</a>
      </li>
      <li>
       <a href="test_webpage.html#feedback">FEEDBACK</a>
      </li>
     </ul>
     <div id='about'>
      <a id="about" name='about'></a>
      <img src="https://image.ibb.co/ft1bSv/cover.jpg" alt="cover">
      <div id='about.container'> 
      <h2>About:</h2>
      <p>We are a small family owned convenience store! We have operating since the early 2000s.</p>
     </div>
     </div>
     <div id='products'>
      <a id="products" name='products'></a>
     </div>
     <div id='coupons'>
      <a id="coupons" name='coupons'></a>
     </div>
     <div id='feedback'>
      <a id="feedback" name='feedback'>
      </a></div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: If I understood correctly you just need a reset search for nomarlize css and add that. To illustrate what you need add this to your css and test it *{margin: 0;} https://jsfiddle.net/0w2xagxc/2/ if you inspect the body tag you can see that there is an 8px margin, that is why you see that space.

Comment: I'd rather use `html,body {margin: 0;}` instead of `*{margin: 0;}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to disable the margin (https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_margin.asp) of your body tag. You can do this in your css. Look at what I did at the top of this css file. That should work.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: mediumblue;
  text-align: center;
  object-position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  top: 0;
}
li {
  display: inline-block;
}
li a {
  display: block;
  color: white;
  padding: 14px 50px;
  text-decoration: none;
}
li a:hover:not(.active) {
  background-color: darkblue;
  font-style: italic;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <!-- Navigation Bar -->
    <ul>
        <li>
            <a href="test_webpage.html#about">ABOUT</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="test_webpage.html#products">PRODUCTS</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="test_webpage.html#coupons">COUPONS</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="test_webpage.html#feedback">FEEDBACK</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
    <div id='about'>
        <a id="about" name='about'></a>
        <img src="https://image.ibb.co/ft1bSv/cover.jpg" alt="cover">
        <div id='about.container'> 
        <h2>About:</h2>
        <p>We are a small family owned convenience store! We have operating since the early 2000s.</p>
    </div>
    </div>
    <div id='products'>
        <a id="products" name='products'></a>
    </div>
    <div id='coupons'>
        <a id="coupons" name='coupons'></a>
    </div>
    <div id='feedback'>
        <a id="feedback" name='feedback'>
        </a></div>
</body>
</html>
```